# php redis insert a data at a same time with few queues error

Tags: php, redis, concurrency, insert

There are 3 queues in redis.
If I insert a data at a same time with different browsers, both requests are accepted.
I get 2 duplicated records. Any helps?

For example, the first request is on the 1st queue.
At the second request, 2nd queue is searched for finding the data.
But the data doesn't exist in the queue.
The second request is inserted on the queue.

Is it understandable?

```
public function save($evt_no, $type = "redis") {
    $name = '';
    $res = true;
    try{
        $headers = getallheaders();
        $bodys = $_REQUEST;
        $session = $_SESSION;

        foreach ($_FILES as $fileKey=>$fileVal) {
            if ($fileVal['error'] == 0) {
                try {
                    $uploaded_row = $this->fileL->upload('queueEventParticipant', $fileKey, array() ,'queue');
                } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                    throw $ex;
                }
                $bodys['file'][_return_numeric($fileKey)] = $uploaded_row;
            }
        }

        $data = array(
            'header' => $headers,
            'body' => $bodys,
            'session' => $session
        );
        $data['body']['evt_no'] = $evt_no;
        $data = json_encode($data);

        if($type == "redis"){
            $name = $this->attendQueueRedisService->setNewRsvp($data);
        } else {
            throw new \Exception("No exist");
        }
    } catch (\Exception $ex){
        log_message("error", $ex->getMessage());
        throw $ex;
    }

    if($res){
        return $name;
    } else {
        return "Error";
    }
}

class AttendQueueRedisService extends CI_Model {
    private $redisClient;
    private $redisConfig;

    const PREFIX_DONE = 'done_';
    const PREFIX_ERROR = 'error_';

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if ($this->load->config('redis', true, true)) {
            $this->redisConfig = $this->config->config['redis'];
        }

        $this->redisClient = new Redis();
        $this->redisClient->connect($this->redisConfig['hostname'], $this->redisConfig['port']);
        $this->redisClient->auth($this->redisConfig['auth']);
        $this->redisClient->select($this->redisConfig['queue']);
    }

    public function setNewRsvp($data) {
        $key = uniqid('rsvp_'.gethostname().'_',true).':redis';
        $this->redisClient->set($key, $data, 60 * 30);

        return $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a section of the code which shows how you process the data.  At the moment it's difficult to understand what may be happening.

Comment: I added the code! @NigelRen

Comment: I search the library for semaphore 
https://github.com/cheprasov/php-redis-lock
https://github.com/php-lock/lock#phpredismutex

It would be helpful?